# HELP i cant install anything

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, update-manager, ppa

i tried editing /etc/apt/sources.list and hono of the ULRs below appear in it. thanks in advance

btw im running 12.04

```
root@p:~# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
Hit http:// archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http:// dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                                                                                                            
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                                                                                                       
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                                                                                                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                                                                                                        
Hit http://  ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                                                                                                        
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                                                                                                        
Get:1 http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg [316 B]                                                                                                               
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                                                                                         
Hit http:// archive.canonical.com precise Release                                                                                                                        
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                                                                                            
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                                                                                            
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                                                                                            
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                                                                                            
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                                                                                            
Hit http:/ /dl.google.com stable Release                                                                                                                                  
Hit http:/ /extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                                                                                                             
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                                                                 
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources/DiffIndex                                 
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                           
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex            
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                                                            
Hit http:// archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                                                                          
Hit http:// dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                                                                                                        
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                                                                                                          
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                                                 
Hit http:// archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex                                                                                         
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                                                       
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                           
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                              
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                                                                         
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                                                                   
Hit http:// archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                                                                                           
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                                                                                                   
Ign http:// extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                          
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                          
Ign http:// dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                                                                              
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                                                    
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                                              
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                                                     
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources/DiffIndex                                                                          
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                                                                    
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                           
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                                                          
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                           
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                                     
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                                                         
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                                                        
Err http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                                 
  404  Not Found
Hit https: //private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                   
Err http: //ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                           
  404  Not Found
Err http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                                                                 
  404  Not Found
Hit https:// private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                       
Err http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                                                  
  404  Not Found
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB                                                       
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                    
Ign http:// extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_GB                                                       
Hit https:// private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                                                  
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB                                                                          
Get:2 https:// private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex [357 B]                                     
Ign https:// private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                         
Hit http:// apt.insynchq.com precise Release.gpg                                                                   
Ign http:// extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                                          
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                    
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB                                 
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en              
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB           
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en              
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB           
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                                    
Ign http:// dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_GB                                      
Hit http:// apt.insynchq.com precise Release                           
Ign http:// dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                    
Hit http:// apt.insynchq.com precise/non-free i386 Packages
Ign https:// private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_GB
Ign https:// private-ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Hit http:// apt.insynchq.com precise/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                      
Ign http:// apt.insynchq.com precise/contrib TranslationIndex           
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release
Ign http:// apt.insynchq.com precise/non-free TranslationIndex
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex  
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex    
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages  
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_GB
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en_GB
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en_GB  
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en     
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http:// apt.insynchq.com precise/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http:// apt.insynchq.com precise/contrib Translation-en
Ign http:// apt.insynchq.com precise/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http:// apt.insynchq.com precise/non-free Translation-en
Fetched 316 B in 8s (36 B/s)                                                                                                                                             
W: GPG error: http:// ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F191A5A8844C542
W: Failed to fetch http:// ppa.launchpad.net/xorg--edgers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http:// ppa.launchpad.net/xorg--edgers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http:// ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/gambas3/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http:// ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/gambas3/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: please visit this [website](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) and rebuild your sources.list file or remove PPA which are causing error

Comment: What exactly you can't install?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The command after "&&" doesn't get executed when you have an error in the first command. Use || or ; instead. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/command-line-what-is-the-purpose-of )

So after updating (with sudo apt-get update), just do a

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

on another line/command (if you don't want to use || or ;). 
You should also verify your sources list is still valid (to get rid of the errors in your apt-get update command so you can do &&, and makes it run faster) - so check all your warnings "W:" for source URLs and make sure they are current; if they've been discontinued, just remove them from your software sources.

EDIT:
To remove software sources (I'm assuming you use Unity):
Go to Software Centre > Edit > Software Sources (or run 'software-properties-gtk').

Then scroll down on the "Software Sources" tab and uncheck the repositories giving you trouble. (You should add the new updated repositories if you still want software from them. For Xorg Edgers, check out & read https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa ).

Comment: how do i remove them from the software sources? thanks

Comment: follow this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) from SirCharlo

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can follow the one @younes linked too.

Comment: this problem is not about how to use `&&` or `||`

Comment: The problem came about because of the underlying cause that the OP didn't know what && actually does - specifically that it won't run the second command when the first gives an error. The OP could still install stuff (executed "apt-get dist-upgrade" by itself). Hence why I included stuff about "&&" and "||" in my answer. I also go through why the 1st command is giving an error and how to fix it, so that the entire line with 2 commands joined by "&&" can be run with the OP's intention.

Answer (score -1):

I also underwent the same scenario once I installed the Ubuntu Operating system on my laptop. Try this.

Open the terminal and type the below command and execute.

> sudo apt-get update

Comment: this is what he is doing and gettng error. voting down